# Unable to setup SlidingMenu for Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to implement https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu in my project but keeps getting error after errors. I followed up some guides and got through some but was eventually stuck.

I have added in:

```
public class _iSellCrazyItem extends SherlockPreferenceActivity
```

But when i tried to add a menu into onCreate, most of the resources isn't found.
I tried copying the menu.xml into my project and it removes an error.

[image: code]

When i hover over the red line, it gives

> > (item) cannot be resolved or is not a type.

Edit: Changed to

```
public class _iSellCrazyItem extends SlidingFragmentActivity
```

but still, these 3 lines cannot be resolved

```
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to exentds `SlidingFragmentActivity` instead of `SherlockPreferenceActivity`. Did you add the sliding menu library correctly to your project?

Comment: yuup found out i was extending the wrong thing, updated the post with new errors

Comment: do you actualy have those resources?

Comment: ohh, im supposed to copy from the source into my existing project?

Comment: I dunno. I have the whole sourcecode from the library but it does not contains resources

Comment: do you have a guide to importing the slidermenu from start?

Comment: there is no guide. If you was able to import SlidingFragmentActivity, you have imported it correctly

Comment: Instead of taking classes, Add sliding menu library reference to your project.Then you will get all properties(resources and ohter classes too) Including answer of @blackbelt.

Comment: i have implemented the thing but when i start the app, it crashes immediately. I'll go make a new post now. For the mean while i'll mark this as answer as it solves the requested question